# sketchflow navigatetoscreenaction popup

Tags: expression-blend, sketchflow

I am using SketchFlow for a prototype.  Right now when the user clicks certain 'links' a trigger is excuted which calls navigatetoscreenaction and I supply the target screen.  The problem is instead of going to this screen and leaving my main window, I want my target screen to popup into a modal dialog.  Can you accomplish this with Sketchflow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you might have to code it up yourself. If you truly want a dialog you will have to do it in the event handler for the item you are clicking. You would do it just like any other dialog on the platform you are using.

If you just want to simulate it, you could make the screen into a component screen and use visual states to hide/show it. Made it hidden in the base state, and create a show state that you trigger with a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

yes you sure can, with a component screen. Right click on your source screen in the sketchflow map and there it  is.